# Writing Junit test cases for Struts

Tags: java, junit, struts

Can I write test cases for struts action class? That is, I would like to test execute method of an existing struts action class, where I can check what is the return ActionForward and also the content of form which is being set up in execute method. An example would be helpful.

Thanks
Kamal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is only [StrutsTestCase](http://strutstestcase.sourceforge.net/). But this is for JUnit 3, not JUnit 4, so it seems to be pretty out of date.

The other alternatives you have come from [How perform Junit tests with Struts - Ibatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491503/how-perform-junit-tests-with-struts-ibatis), which suggest [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/) (again pretty old) or [Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/) (which has been retired).

If I had to, I would start with `StrutsTestCase`. Here is a sample Test Case from the site:

```
public class TestLoginAction extends MockStrutsTestCase {
    public TestLoginAction(String testName) { super(testName); }

    public void testSuccessfulLogin() {
       setRequestPathInfo("/login");
       addRequestParameter("username","deryl");
       addRequestParameter("password","radar");
       actionPerform();
       verifyForward("success");
    }
}
```

I have used `StrutsTestCase` a long time ago, and as far as I can remember it worked fairly well.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, StrutsTestCase is turning out to be very helpful.

Comment: Hi @matthew-farwell, do you know to test transition from ActionForm to Action. I have used setActionForm(myForm), then call actionPerform(). But it seemed to not work correctly.Do you know any samples for ActionForm unit test? Thanks